# Alternatives to Mailman

Tags: untagged

I need to replace or rebuild our old mail list server. This isn't a high volume list server and we are hoping to replace it with a free or OSS solution. I've setup mailman before, but it is starting to show it's age in a bad way. One of the requirements is a web based management utility as we are hoping to delegate the management of individual lists off to different people. We are a mixed Windows + Linux shop, but would strongly prefer the latter.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

**Edit:** I guess I should have made this a bit clearer. I am looking for mailing list software not an announcement system. It should support discussion lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try [Sympa](http://www.sympa.org/). AFAIK it is very good with delegated management options.

Maybe even better than mailman's (I am not using it right now, so you have to try it yourself).

Comment: Sympa is also looking like a good candidate, I'll add it to my list thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Gentoo uses [mlmmj](http://mlmmj.org/) for their mailing lists.

There is also the ever ubiquitous Wikipedia link of [Mailing List softwares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_mailing_lists), including things like [Majordomo](http://www.greatcircle.com/majordomo/) and [phplist](http://www.phplist.com/)

From a brief skim, either mlmmj or phplist would likely meet your needs.

Comment: mlmmj is looking very promising, although the documentation on their official web site is seriously lacking. phplist is a "one-way email announcement delivery system" which is not what I am looking for perhaps I should have clarified it as a discussion list.

Answer (score 1):

[Lyris ListManager](http://www.lyris.com/solutions/listmanager/) is popular among lots of list server admins. If you have under 200 people per list you can get away with the free version.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution could be [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/), some interesting features are:

- Open/View Tracking tells you how many users opened your email message.
- Click Tracking tracks links and URLs.
  Statistics can be viewed by message,
  URL or subscriber.
- Templates are completely customizable, and make site integration a breeze.
- The HTML Editor allows you to edit html messages from phplist using FCKeditor. TinyMCE is also available.